# Jquery Mobile -- how to Override Height and width of select box.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<select id="selectId" name="name1" style="height:10% !important;" >
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option>xxx</option>
    <option>yyy</option>
    <option selected="selected">rrr</option>
    <option>ggg</option>
    <option>fff</option>
    <option>qqq</option>
</select>
```

How can i set the width and height for select. I am using jquery mobile css and i am unable to make this work. please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this css class `.ui-select` try this:

```
.ui-select{
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
}
```

Check the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k4a3s/)

If you want to affect only that select use the id to target that like this in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selectId').closest('.ui-select').addClass('select_small')
})
```

With this you can add this class:

```
.select_small{
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
}
```

Check another **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k4a3s/1/)**

Comment: thanks it help me but can you tell me how can apply this only for a particular select it applies to all in the page..

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying exact height such as 100px, or if you want it to be with percentage, make sure your container has height as well.

```
<select id="selectId" name="name1" style="height:100px !important;" >
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F2952/

this runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using jquery for this you can use

```
$("#selectId").width("enter your width");
$("#selectId").height(enter your height);
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of `select` seems to be dependent on the `options`. So, I would style it like:

```
select option{height:50px}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/F2952/1/).